# Why XY coordinates offset when output to PDF/PNG in Print Composer of QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.10

Here's my image when i output to PNG.Same result when output to PDF. Whats the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out why this offset happens. Its because of OpenLayers plugin google base-map. Instead of that plugin i used QuickMapServices plugin and loaded OSM standard basemap. This fixes the issue.